# How to put a throttle on a vacuum cleaner to reduce power consumption

Tags: motor, inverter, power-consumption

I´m no engineer in any way so I don´t know if the question was correctly asked.

The thing is I have a 1000w normal household vacuum cleaner that I want to use in my RV(recreation vehicle). The problem is that the 1000w is too much and draining my 200Am 12 batteries quick. I run the vacuum cleaner through a 1500W inverter that takes the 12V and convert it into 230V.

How can reduce current of the vacuum cleaner to a 500W vacuum cleaner level?

---

This is the [vacuum cleaner](http://www.biltema.se/sv/Hem/Stad-och-tvatt/Dammsugare/Vat--och-torrdammsugare/Vat--och-torrdammsugare-WD-100010-2000034026/).  And this is the 
[12v to 230v inverter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/inverter-12v-220v-1500w-3000w-peaking-pure-sine-wave-power-inverters-converters-with-Remote-control/32781486911.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.QR0ch6). I did not want to shock the inverter buy using the 1000w cleaner, i know the inverter can handle but anyway

Comment: Best option get one of those small 12v car ones or only use your mains one when connected to the grid...

Comment: I know that but this is about if one can convert/throttle a 1000w cleaner. I like to rebuild stuff :)

Comment: if you read my comment about the flow and that answer then you should follow the principle.

Comment: Wait for Apple to come out with their new IOT vacuum cleaner, the iSuck.

Comment: Cant understand how difficult it can be to answer a question here. I get advice to buy a 12v vacuum cleaner. Most of the talk is about how much air suction one lose when reducing current, like that has anything to do with my question, Transistor answer my question and got som upvot to. Mybe I should change my Q to be about suction lose now with the brilliant answer from @Transistor. Thanks OlinLathrop to actually answering the Q

Comment: @Erik that's because what they are telling you is you would be cheaper to go buy another vacuum cleaner. Since from that aspect it is a non-starter you cant expect anyone to take the time to give you much on an answer.

Comment: I don´t care about buying a 12V cheaper cleaner because this is not about money or convenience. My Q is being down voted not because it´s a bad Q but because you all noobs cant answer it LOL. This is Humankind in the making LOL

Comment: You are being down voted because you are missing the obvious. You cannot squeeze blood out of a turnip, and you cannot run a 1500 watt cleaner at 500 watts. It *needs* that power just to have enough torque to run the motor, much less suck. VTC.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question directly, you can get a variac and dial down the AC voltage going into the vacuum cleaner.  It should take less power with lower input voltage.

However, the better answer is to **get a different vacuum cleaner**.  The one you have is simply not appropriate for the situation.  There is no "simple" way, especially for someone not that familiar with electronics, to modify a vacuum cleaner for less power.

There are vacuum cleaners that are intended to run directly from the 12 V of a car.  Or get a smaller unit that doesn't draw so much power in the first place, then dedicate that to your RV.

Comment: So reducing the power in do you expect the performance to be refuced - hiw do you think the flow rate will change and therefore the “suck”...

Comment: @Sol: Obviously the suction would be reduced due to slower impeller speed.  Whether the power can be reduced enough and still have the vacuum cleaner be useful is dependent on the construction of that particular model, and to some extent how much degredation of performance the user is willing to tolerate.  These are things we don't know here.

Comment: 99% of commercially available vacuum cleaners will use a Universal Motor design. With that type of motor, a lower voltage will indeed slow it down, so a variac (variable voltage transformer) could be used to change the power consumption by lowering the speed and reducing the suction. That variac will likely cost more than just buying a smaller vacuum cleaner.